# Format SQL Server query results for 3D histogram

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, excel, histogram

I have a table like this, that stores 3D histograms data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HISTOGRAM_3D](
    [H3D_X] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [H3D_Y] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [H3D_Z] [decimal](6, 2) NULL
)
```

I use this query to get histogram's data:

```
SELECT h3d.H3D_X, H3D_Y, SUM(h3d.H3D_Z) AS VALUE 
    FROM HISTOGRAM_3D h3d
    GROUP BY h3d.H3D_X, H3D_Y
    ORDER BY h3d.H3D_X ASC
```

Now, what I get is something like this:

```
H3D_X | H3D_Y | VALUE
H3D_X | H3D_Y | VALUE
H3D_X | H3D_Y | VALUE
H3D_X | H3D_Y | VALUE
....
```

But, I would like to format the result to the following format, because it's very easy to display the graph using MS Excel.

```
---------------------- | ---- H3D_X VALUES -----------
H3D_Y VALUES | VALUE | VALUE | VALUE  ......
H3D_Y VALUES | VALUE | VALUE | VALUE  ......
H3D_Y VALUES | VALUE | VALUE | VALUE  ......
H3D_Y VALUES | VALUE | VALUE | VALUE  ......
```

Is it possible to implement this in SQL?

Comment: I think if you show a bit realistic data and an expected output that will be more helpful rather than `H3D_Y VALUES` or `Values`, `Values` dont know what these magic words mean and what you expect there.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you want the data formatted for Excel please? I don't understand your description.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! One possible solution is using a dynamic query like this:

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query_histogram_3d  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT',' + QUOTENAME(H3D_X) 
                FROM SL_HISTOGRAM_3D
                WHERE H3D_CL_ID = @CYCLE_ID
                GROUP BY H3D_X
                ORDER BY H3D_X
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query_histogram_2d = N'SELECT H3D_CL_ID, H3D_Y, ' + @cols + N' FROM 
            (
            SELECT H3D_CL_ID, H3D_X, H3D_Y, SUM(H3D_Z) AS VALUE
            FROM SL_HISTOGRAM_3D
            WHERE H3D_CL_ID = ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),@CYCLE_ID) + N'
            GROUP BY H3D_CL_ID, H3D_X, H3D_Y
        ) x
        PIVOT 
        (
            MAX(VALUE)
            FOR H3D_X IN (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query_histogram_3d;
```

END

Thankyou!